# Storing the result of an SQL call in a php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code below and it's working as it should however instead of echoing the results to the screen, I need to store the results in a php variable called $var. How would I go about doing that?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id_member FROM smf_members WHERE FIND_IN_SET(24,additional_groups)";

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sqluser', 'sqlpass');
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test_db");
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['id_member'];
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve here is a few possible ways of doing this

```
$var = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var .= $row['id_member'] . "\n";
}

$var = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['id_member'];
}
```

Comment: with a small amount of adjustment your code is the one that seemed to work out of the box. I changed the + sign to a . which I don't know if it was a typo or needed, but either way it seems to work for me. Thanks.

Comment: No problems yes the + was meant to be a dot, small typo fixed now

Answer (score 2):

replace `echo` with `$var[]`.

That will push each result onto the end of the array.  It would probably be good to define the variable first.

```
$var = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $var[] = $row['id_member'];
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong put when I tried to echo the variable all that is displayed on the screen is the word Array and not the result of the query which is what I expected. Am I missing something ?

Comment: that's how php echo's arrays.  use `var_dump($var);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id_member FROM smf_members WHERE FIND_IN_SET(24,additional_groups)";

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sqluser', 'sqlpass');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test_db");

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

$v = array(); // $v instead of $var, since var is a keyword and may cause troubles

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
array_push($v, $row['id_member']); 
// or
//$v[] = $row['id_member'];
}

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: In older php versions it could, I think.

Comment: I changed the variable name to $test and tried your code but all I saw on the screen when I echoed out the variable was the word Array like in the other example above. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: `print_r($test);`

`foreach($test as $key => $value)
  echo '$test[' . $key . ']='.$value;`

Answer (score 1):

If the select statement will return more than one result, then you need to store the values in an array:

```
$member_ids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $member_ids[] = $row['id_member'];
}
```

If the select statement will return a single result (you can make sure by appending a `LIMIT 1` to the value of the `$sql` variable).

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$member_id = $row['id_member'];
```

Comment: of course it is   `$member_ids[] = $row['id_member'];` and not   $member_ids = $row['id_member']; cannot edit

Comment: @yokoloko: It was a typo, of course that's what I meant. I don't think it's worth a down-vote though. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Who said i down voted it :) I'm not the only user on SO @shef. I just pointed it out for Amy

Comment: @yokoloko: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I wasn't referring to you when I talked about the down-vote.

Comment: I don't see a differnce in the 2, but anyway all I seen when I echo out the variable $member_id is Array like in the other examples above. Not sure what I am missing here

Comment: @Amy: There is a difference in the two. If the first one will store many member ids, the second one will store a single one. You can output the first one like `echo $member_ids[0]`, `echo $member_ids[1]`, `echo $member_ids[2]`, and so one. Whereas you can output the second one simply by `echo $member_id`.

Comment: I understood that part sorry I meant were you said you made a typo. I did not see a difference between the corrected and non corrected versions but I am tired so prob missing something. Anyway I understand what I was doing wrong. The result I expected was ALL the ids in one shot which the code from Tristen provided to me. Thanks for the explanation tho.

Comment: @Amy: Ahh... I edited it already. It was `$member_ids = $row['id_member'];`.

Comment: Now I see the typo, missing brackets after $member_ids. Everyone makes mistakes :) Thanks for the help tho

Comment: @Amy: Once you have the array of `$member_ids` you can manipulate it any way you like. Even echo it at once every id starting at a new line like `echo implode("\n", $member_ids);`.

Comment: Thanks I guess I still have alot to learn. Very helpful information which I use the next time I need to do this.